# mktime function is not displaying correct month name

Tags: php, expressionengine, php-5.3

**All of you please try to understand {segment_4} is not a variable.** its taking 4th value from URL e.g. www.example.com/panel/vals/2015/09 i.e. 09

I am using mktime function in Expression engine but its giving incorrect month name even i have set localization setting from admin panel to india kolkata here is the code :-

```
<?php echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, {segment_4}, 10));?>
```

here `segment_4` is month in digit eg. 09 but its showing **December** it should be **September** I researched for it every where said that function is correct I have to set anything else in expression engine ?

One more thing when i used this code :-

```
echo date_default_timezone_get();
```

then its showing **Europe/London** even i have changed time zone in EE by india/kolkata

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try using a dollar in front of the variable name and you dont need the curly brackets either i.e. `$segment_4`

Comment: I don't think this question is related to expressionengine. I think it is pure PHP.

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is no variable and have you ever used expression engine its necessary in EE to use { } symbol

Comment: @Amarnasan ok means you are ignoring EE localization setting.. i know its pure php code but its not working in EE thus i want to ask is there any setting for time zone in EE rather than localization setting.

Comment: Have you tried to call that `mktime` with `9` instead of  `{segment_4}`, just to check if you actually get September?

Comment: `09` is different from `9`. It is there silently converted to `0`

Comment: @Amarnasan with digit 9 its showing September but with 09 its showing December i am getting 09 in segment_4

Comment: And that proves that it had nothing to do with localization: With a 9 you get September as expected.

Comment: @Amarnasan but why 09 is coming instead of 9 its a BIG que. right ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, you have a '09', which is interpreted as an octal 9, which is an error, (because symbol '9' doesn't exist in octal) and thus it is converted to 0. Which is interpreted by mktime as december. From @fpietka comment.

I'd suggest using

```
<?php echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, ltrim($segment_4, "0"), 10));?>
```

Comment: so know what i have to do because 3 website are working on this code  with multi site management lots of template are using this code..

Comment: @Rizier123 you have answer ?

Comment: @Abhay `ltrim($number, "0")`

Comment: Still showing December with (int) or with Abhay's ltrim?

Comment: Then check with ltrim as Rizier123 suggested. And if that doesn't work, I'm sorry but you'll have to edit the controller that uses this template and do it from there. You have to be sure you're passing a 9, and not a 0.

Comment: @Amarnasan not works and we can not change the link bec. its created by EE look https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/archive_month_links.html we have no option to change it

Comment: Check this... <?php $this->EE =& get_instance();echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, ltrim($this->EE->uri->segment(4),"0"), 10));?>